# Can I connect more than one breakout board to the Raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-2

I want to use [Magstripe Reader](https://www.adafruit.com/product/853),
[Fingerprint sensor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/751) and the [NFC reader](https://www.adafruit.com/product/364) all together, 
Is it possible and if so it would be nice if you can reffer me where I can read how to do it,
Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While one could of course connect multiple devices to one Pi this cannot be answered in a general fashion. Please edit to include specific details for the devices to be connected... and remove the signature while you're at it (see tour and helpcenter to learn more).

Comment: I see you have added links to your question identifying the specific peripherals you are interested in connecting to a RPi.  Let us say it is possible.  But since these peripherals are not specifically designed for the RPi there is considerable work to be done both in hardware and software.  Guessing, based on the general terms used in your question, this will be challenging for you.  At this point, I need to also point out that even asking about how to connect just 1 of these peripherals  will take more than 1 stackexchange question / answer...

Comment: ...I suggest using the forums where you are purchasing these peripherals and start a discussion there.  A forum sounds like the format you need to get started.  However, if you are new to this, this will be a challenge.  A RPi is way more complex in terms of software and what it can do than an Arduino.  And the examples on the sellers site are connecting some of these peripherals only to an Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three items are going to be difficult to directly link to the RasPi.

The MagStripe Reader and the Fingerprint reader are basically 5v devices and need TTL serial. The problem is that there is only one real serial port on the Raspberry Pi. You can get USB serial ports and you'd need two of them.

The NFC breakout board can use 3.3V I2C or SPI. This can be done directly through the Raspberry Pi's GPIO and the proper library.

My personal preference would be to use one of the small Arduino clones (or a PIC) that runs at 5 volts and has two serial ports. Or, if I couldn't find one with two serial ports, I would bit-bang one of them (using the hardware timers to emulate a serial port); this is much easier on a microcontroller than on a Raspberry Pi. The microcontroller can then communicate with the Raspberry Pi through I2C or SPI.

Just remember that you will need a level-shifter to go from a 5v device to the Raspberry Pi which is a 3.3v device. I would use [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757) board.

Happy Making